# how to get concrete class object from shared_ptr to abstract class objects

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I have vector of shared_ptrs to objects that are derived from Abstract class

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Abstract>> objects;
```

the following fails:

```
Concrete* c = objects[0].get()
```

With:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘Abstract*’ to ‘Concrete*
```

How can I get access to object of concrete type

Comment: Pointer cast? dynamic_cast or std::dynamic_pointer_cast  
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must get a pointer to the derived class, use `dynamic_cast`.

```
Concrete* c = dynamic_cast<Concrete*>(objects[0].get());
if ( c != nullptr )
{
    // Use c
}
```

If you need to just access a member function or member variable but not the pointer itself, you can use [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).

```
auto cptr = std::static_pointer_cast<Concrete>(objects[0]);
if ( cptr )
{
   // Use cptr
}
```

Using `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` also has the same benefits that you get when  using smart pointers in general.

Comment: That's not accurate. You can access member function of variable either way. std::dynamic_pointer_cast creates a new std::shared_ptr, with all the overhead of a reference-counted pointer. If you need a new pointer with shared ownership use that. Otherwise a naked pointer with dynamic_cast is good enough.